# Refer to a Module within the Module in Python

Tags: python, import

I have a directory structure for a module like the following:

```
- foo
   - __init__.py
   - gui.py
```

I use the foo module from other places. Now I want to use something from the foo module in gui.py, but when I try to, I get this:

```
jsternberg@aquila:~$ python foo/gui.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo/gui.py", line 3, in <module>
    import foo
ImportError: No module named foo
```

How do I get the foo module from inside of it?

Comment: You're already there. Just import whatever you want to import...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory containing `foo/` isn't in `sys.path` when you invoke it that way.

```
python -m foo.gui
```